# Does Samza work with ResourceManager in HA?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-samza

Does anyone have Samza working with resource manager in HA?  If so, what do I set `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` to in `yarn-site.xml`?

If I set it to the first of my RMs, the the job submission works ok if I submit the job from that RM and the RM is the active one.  If the RM machine that I run the job submission from is not active, I get connection refused errors on port 8032.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we have samza running with RM in HA mode. Basically ensure yarn-site.xml has the properties defined below set for sure. This will ensure that the job submission will try connecting to the other RM if the first one doesn't succeed.

```
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>yarn_resource_manager_hostname</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
      <value>yarn_cluster_id</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
      <value>rm1,rm2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm1</name>
      <value>yarn_resource_manager_hostname</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2</name>
      <value>yarn_resource_manager2_hostname</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm1</name>
      <value>yarn_resource_manager_hostname:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2</name>
      <value>yarn_resource_manager2_hostname:8032</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: my ports were different but otherwise spot on

Comment: The latest builds of Samza also support NM recovery and RM work-preserving recovery. Turning on these two recovery features when you enable HA is a very good idea.